# Content Security Policy stops inline script execution, in spite of report-only mode

Tags: javascript, inline

I have a CSP in place with 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only' mode and report-uri.  I have an inline JavaScript running which the CSP prohibits.  My understanding was the JavaScript would still be allowed to run while in report-only mode, but will be reported to the report-uri link.  It does gets documented in the report-uri link, but it also stops the page from loading with the following error on the Chrome console: "**[Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".**".  Why is the CSP being enforced in 'Report-only' mode?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to happen when I set the CSP along with the Header '**Header set Set-Cookie: HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict**' in Apache 2.2.3.  I removed this header and the CSP works in true report only mode.