# Difference between enforce Content security policy and CSP report only

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I am working on Content Security policy to add to my pages. I am confused between term enforce CSP and CSP report only. what is the difference between those two and how they are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSP puts a number of restrictions on sources of content and specific actions. As this has the potential to break a lot of functionality there is also a report only mode, which can be thought of as a test mode. In report only you will get the same browser errors about violations, they are just not enforced and are marked as report-only. For a valid report-only CSP you must define a report-uri to send reports to. Gathering reports from real users for a while will identify problems with your policy before switching to enforce mode. But you will likely also get some false positives due to proxy rewrites, browser extensions, malware etc. Report-only doesn't give any protections and violations will only be visible for users who take a look at dev tools. A strict enforce CSP is essential in protecting your users from a number of web attacks such as XSS and clickjacking.

Comment: Will we receive reports for enforce mode as well? I am trying see whether we can populate metrics for the same

Comment: Yes, define report-to or report-uri and reports will be sent.

Comment: Yes and no... Report-only also DOES block resources, albeit not always. At least this is how it happens now in Chrome/Vivaldi with external http pictures, after the lagacy site was wrapped into https, most pictures just fail to load due to report-only poilcy violation. Crazy... This might have soemthign with it, or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836539

Comment: i wonder if enforced mixed images "upgrade" also kicked in, https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4926989725073408 - the image in question was existing on plain HTTP, but 404ed on HTTPS. It is so nice when monopolies enforce happinness on you, often you can guess which direction a bowel of happinness would be poured on you from, but sometimes you don't....